# Loki: Sound settings is not recognizing my audio devices, alsamixer is

Tags: release-loki, indicator-sound

[image]
In the wingpanel, the sound indicator icon is disabled (with an x in front of the speaker icon), even if I unmute/raise the volume up.

alsamixer is working fine and recognizes my devices and audio card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because I mounted my `/home` folder at my ntfs partition with default options, and pulseaudio wasn't being able to start because my home folder's owner was root.

Since `chown` didn't work in this case, changed the mount options in `/etc/fstab` from this:

```
defaults 0 2
```

to this:

```
uid:1000,gid:1000,umask:0000 0 2
```

That probably brings me security issues and would give me issues with having other users, but it is working as expected and I am the only user in my computer.